# Building a cloned github project in maven through the command line

Tags: maven, command-line

I am unfamiliar with the command to build a project that I have cloned from a github repository and created a local copy of.

I want to build it using maven through the command line.

I have already installed maven.

Could someone let me know how this is possible? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to run: `mvn package` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I did and the build failed but it worked with mvn compile. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What exactly failed and what kind of message has been shown?